# Markdown language inside R chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R studio Version 0.99.485.
I have to do many reports based on one input vector, so I have decided to write for loop in R Markdown (R studio).

I have a problem that seems easy to solve but I couldn't find the answer on net.

Here is my code:

````
```{r forensis, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
load(file = "E:/data/R/Forensic_reports/fdata.RData")
for (i in 1:length(osobni_podaci$Oib)) {
  cat("### UPIT ZA OIB: ", oibreq[i], '  \n')
  cat('### STATUS OIB-A  \n')
  cat('Status: ',ifelse(oib_status$X_status[i] == 1, 'Aktivan', 'Neaktivan'), '  \n')
  cat('### OSNOVNI PODACI  \n')
  cat("### Ime: ", osobni_podaci$Ime[i], '  \n')
  cat("### Prezime: ", osobni_podaci$Prezime[i], '  \n')
}
```
````

Here is the output:

```
UPIT ZA OIB: 10755053324
STATUS OIB-A
Status: Aktivan
### OSNOVNI PODACI
### Ime: MISLAV
### Prezime: ŠAGOVAC
### UPIT ZA OIB: 93335620125
### STATUS OIB-A
Status: Aktivan
### OSNOVNI PODACI
### Ime: SUZANA
### Prezime: CESAREC NOETHIG
```

It is not seen from the output, but the headings are right for first 3 lines.

Then, after the 4th line I doesn't recognize hashtags ### as 'Header 3', but instead just print three ###.

In nutshell, **how to preserve markdown language rules inside r chunks?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In markdown, there must be an empty line before a header, so you just need to add a `\n` before the `###`:

````
```{r forensis, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
load(file = "E:/data/R/Forensic_reports/fdata.RData")
for (i in 1:length(osobni_podaci$Oib)) {
  cat("\n### UPIT ZA OIB: ", oibreq[i], '  \n')
  cat('\n### STATUS OIB-A  \n')
  cat('Status: ',ifelse(oib_status$X_status[i] == 1, 'Aktivan', 'Neaktivan'), '  \n')
  cat('\n### OSNOVNI PODACI  \n')
  cat("\n### Ime: ", osobni_podaci$Ime[i], '  \n')
  cat("\n### Prezime: ", osobni_podaci$Prezime[i], '  \n')
}
```
````

Comment: Thank! Ca you recommend any web page where I can read other rules?